# Jquery for asp.net treeview

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0, treeview

I am using a asp.net tree view control. I want to add the jquery style for the .net tree view control. But i can't do this. Please help me to fix this issue. I need the jquery for smooth expanding and collapse...

This is my design code. Where i can refer the jquery in asp.net control

```
 <asp:TreeView ID="MyTree" PathSeparator="|" ExpandDepth="1" runat="server" NodeIndent="15"
                    ShowLines="true">
                    <RootNodeStyle ImageUrl="~/images/folder-video.png" />
                    <ParentNodeStyle ImageUrl="~/images/root.png" />
                    <NodeStyle ImageUrl="~/images/node.png" />
                    <LeafNodeStyle ImageUrl="~/images/leaf_video.png" />
                    <SelectedNodeStyle BackColor="#B5B5B5"></SelectedNodeStyle>
                    <NodeStyle VerticalPadding="2" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="10pt" HorizontalPadding="2"
                        ForeColor="#000000"></NodeStyle>
                    <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#6666AA"></HoverNodeStyle>
                    <Nodes>
                        <asp:TreeNode Text="Sunbusiness Solution" PopulateOnDemand="True" Value="Demos" />
                    </Nodes>
                </asp:TreeView>
```

Comment: You mean css style? the treeview already expands properly...

Answer (score 1):

I use treeview with checkboxes. On checkbox click  node expands.

```
function InitTreeViewClick(){    $('#" + treevew.ClientID + @" :input').each(function(){  $(this).unbind(); var   a=this.nextSibling; if(a.nodeName=='A')  $(this).bind('click',   function(){a.click();});});}
}

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(InitTreeViewClick);
```

You can modify a.click() for example:   setTimeout(function(){a.click();},3000);

In my case this works perfectly.

And cs file code:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
if (!this.Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("treeview"))
        {
            string script = @"Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(InitTreeViewClick);

                          function InitTreeViewClick(){    $('#" + treevew.ClientID + @" :input').each(function(){ $(this).unbind(); var a=this.nextSibling; if(a.nodeName=='A')  $(this).bind('click',  function(){a.click();});});} ";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "treeview", script, true);
        }
}
```

In your case you can find all links

```
$('#" + treevew.ClientID + @" ).find('a').each( function(){$(this).click(
// your logic 
);});
```

OR

```
 $('#" + treevew.ClientID + @" ).find('a').each(function(){$(this).click(function(){$(this).parentsUntil('table').parent('table').next().css('background','red').slideToggle("slow");});});
```

this code will slowly collapse and expand div with subitems when you click on parent node and background for child nodes will be red on this time.

Final solution (I applied this solution in my project too, because it looks fine).
 ASCX file code:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="treeview" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="inputs" ExpandDepth="0" MaxDataBindDepth="2"
    EnableClientScript="true" ShowCheckBoxes="All" AutoGenerateDataBindings="false"  ShowLines="false" 
     ShowExpandCollapse="false">

</asp:TreeView>
```

and cs file code:

```
 if (!this.Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("treeview")) { string script = @"function InitTreeView(){$('#" + treeview.ClientID + @"' ).find('a').each(function(){$(this).unbind().removeAttr('onclick').removeAttr('href').click(function(){$(this).parentsUntil('table‌​‌​').parent('table').next().slideToggle('slow');});});} Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(InitTreeView);"; ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "treeview", script, true); }
```

I remove href  attribute  with __DoPostBack from tag anchor, because I need to save only checkboxes value. 
Many thanks indeed user 1804985 for your question. :)

Comment: What effect do you want to get?

Comment: Now am using like this..  protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("treeview"))
        {
            string script = @"$('#" + MyTree.ClientID + @" ).find('a').each(function(){$(this).click(function(){$(this).parentsUntil('table').parent('table').next().css('background','red').slideToggle('slow');});})";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "treeview", script, true);
        }
    }

Comment: protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) { if (!this.Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("treeview")) { string script = @"function InitTreeView(){$('#" + MyTree.ClientID + @" ).find('a').each(function(){$(this).click(function(){$(this).parentsUntil('table‌​').parent('table').next().css('background','red').slideToggle('slow');});});}  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(InitTreeView);"; ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "treeview", script, true); } }

Comment: $('#" + MyTree.ClientID + @" ) have to change $('#" + MyTree.ClientID + @" ')